# Reading Ruler for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, software-rec

I'm looking for a reading ruler for Mac OS X.

To be precise: I don't want to measure something. I have to read long texts, which can be very exhausting. A line or marker which is easy to move would help a lot to keep the eyes on the right line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `Firefox` extension called [Paragrasp](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/paragrasp/?src=search) enabling you to read web pages with a marker.

Here is a short decription:

> This Firefox extension adds a highlight to the paragraph you're
>   reading, and with a single keystroke, moves to the next, automatically
>   scrolling the page for you. Features include key configuration, color
>   customization, mouse hiding, and control over scrolling position.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you read PDFs, the free and open-source [**Skim**](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) offers a Reading Bar. Turn it on by going to *View » Show Reading Bar*, or pressing <kbd>Shift-Cmd-B</kbd>.

You move it up and down by <kbd>Alt - ↑</kbd> and <kbd>Alt - ↓</kbd>.

[image]

In *Preferences » Display*, you can change its color or invert it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However most of the time I have to read web pages.

Comment: Ah, fair enough! In the future, please state details like this in your question – otherwise people are bound to make assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

I found this [screen ruler](http://www.pascal.com/software/freeruler/). It's possible to configure it to show only the horizontal ruler and use it as a reading line.